# The grunt compiles every scss except one. Why?

Tags: css, compilation, sass, gruntfile

If I made a file, or change it, the grunt is working perfectly. 
The watch task find the file, noticed the changes, and creates the css files.

Except ONE file.

This:

This is the scss:

```
// Import variables, abstractions, base styles and components.
// Uncomment the next lines and adjust them to your needs.
//@import "variables/{YOUR FILE NAME HERE}";
//@import "abstractions/{YOUR FILE NAME HERE}";
//@import "base/{YOUR FILE NAME HERE}";
//@import "components/{YOUR FILE NAME HERE}";



/*
@import "variables/_colors.scss";
@import "variables/_fonts.scss";
@import "variables/_grid.scss";
@import "variables/_mixins.scss";
*/
@import "variables/_colors";
@import "variables/_fonts";
@import "variables/_mixins";

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img, media {
  max-width: 150%;
}

h1 {
  padding: 1em 0;
  color: $brown;
}

h2 {
  padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
  color: $brown2;
}

h3 {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
   color: $brown2;
}

body { 
  margin: auto;
  background-image: url("../images/background-paper.jpg");
  }


a:link {color: $brown;}
a:visited {color: $brown;}
a:hover {color: $green;}
a:active {color: $green;}


a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*HEADER*/

/*FIRST MENU*/

.pane-superfish-1,
.pane-superfish-2 {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.sf-main-menu {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.sf-menu {
  .active {
    color: $green;
  }
  .leaf {
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  }
}

.sf-menu {   
    margin-top: 2em;
  li {
    li:active {color: $green;}
    a {
      margin: .5em;
      list-style-type: none;
      border-right: 2px solid $brown;
      padding-right: .5em;
    }   
    }
    li:last-child a {
      border-right: none;
      padding-right: 0;
      li:active {color: $green;}
  }
}

/*SECOND MENU*/

.menu {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.sf-menu-content-menu {
  margin-top: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: $secondmenu;
  li .sf-depth-1 {
    a {
    padding: .5em;
    list-style-type: none;
    }
    }
    }

.sf-menu .sf-with-ul + ul {
  /*background: url("../images/background-paper.jpg");*/
  background: $brown2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid $brown;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  @include box-shadow(0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(119,70,40,1));
  li a{
  color: $butter;
  }
  }

.sf-menu .sf-with-ul + ul:after {
  bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(167, 112, 3, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #A77003;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

.sf-menu .sf-with-ul + ul li a:hover {
  background: $fade;
}


.sf-menu li:hover > ul, .sf-menu li.sfHover > ul {
    left: -55px;
}


/*menu-arrow*/

.sf-menu .sf-sub-indicator {
  background: url("../images/arrow-brown.png") no-repeat;
  height: 15px;
  top: 25px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  left: 45%;
}


/* END MENUS*/

.panels-flexible-1 .panels-flexible-row {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  placeholder: valami;
}

.header {  
  max-width: 960px;
  line-height: 1em; 

   .sitetitle {    
    overflow: hidden;   
    opacity: 0.9;
    font-size: $focim;
    font-weight: lighter;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 4em;

    a {
       color: $title;
        margin-left: 1em;
    }
    span {
      padding-left: 1em;
    }
 }  
}

.panels-flexible-2 .panels-flexible-row { /*header*/
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding: 0;
  }

/* HEADER END*/


.panels-flexible-2 .panels-flexible-row {
  padding: 0; 
}
.panels-flexible-region-2-header {
  width: 100%;
}

.panels-flexible-row.panels-flexible-row-2-main-row.clearfix{
  max-width: 960px;
  }

#logo {

  img {
  max-height: 100px; 
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
}

/*SILDESHOW*/

.views_slideshow_cycle_main {
 background-image: url("../images/slideshow-background.jpg");
 border-top: 10px solid $green;
}

/*keskeny rész*/
.views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
}

/*faltól falig érő rész*/
.views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row-item {  

  .views-field.views-field-title {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 1em;    
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: $focim;
    font-weight: lighter;
    a {
      color: $light-yellow;
    }
  }

  .views-field-body {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 1em;
    color: $butter;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

.views-field-field-highlight-image .field-content img { 
    float: right;
    margin-left: 4em;
    border: 7px solid $butter;
    margin: 1em;
  }

/*SILDESHOW END*/

/*CONTENT*/

.pane-title {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  color: $brown;
}

.node__title {
  font-size: $alcim;
}

.views-row {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.panel-display.panel-2col.clearfix {
.views-field-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
  }
}
.pane-node-field-bor-t-k-p {
  img {
    border: 2px solid black;
  }

.pane-entity-field.pane-node-body {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: $fade;
}
}

.pane-node-field-b-vebben a {
  padding: .5em;
  margin: .5em;
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: $fade;
  border: 3px solid $brown;
  border-radius: 15px;
  @include box-shadow(0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(119,70,40,1));
 }

.pane-node-field-b-vebben a:hover {
 @include box-shadow(0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(8,98,27,1));
 border: 3px solid $green;
}

.pane-konyv-konyvek-pane .view-content .views-row {
   @include box-shadow(0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(119,70,40,1));
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.pane-konyv-konyvek-pane .view-content .views-row:hover {
  @include box-shadow(0px 0px 1px 1px $light-yellow);
   background: $fade;
}

/*CONTENT END*/


.footer {
   background-image: url("../images/slideshow-background.jpg");
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 1em;
   a {
    padding: 1em;
    display: block;
   }
}
```

The grunt watch command noticed the changes, and writes DONE. (No error)
But the css does not change.

If I copy this code in an other file. The grunt compiles it to this css:
I have no idea what is this. This is not enough. See?

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address,
big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article,
aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote::before, blockquote::after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

q::before, q::after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=tarsoly.css.map */
```

Nothing more!
Every my scss is working, exept this one.

This is my gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

 grunt.initConfig({
   pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    connect: {
     uses_defaults: {}
   },

    sass: {                              
      dist: {                           
        options: {                     
          style: 'expanded',
          sourceMap: true 
          },
       files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'sites/all/themes/tarsoly/sass/',
        src: ['**/*.scss'],
        dest: 'sites/all/themes/tarsoly/css/',
        ext: '.css'
        }]
       }
       }, 

   watch: {
    css: {
      files: 'sites/all/themes/tarsoly/**/*.scss',
      tasks: [ 'sass' ],
      options: { livereload: true }
      }
      },



 });


// Default task(s).
 grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

// Load Grunt plugins
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass-globbing');
};
```

Can you help me?

Comment: whats your current file structure?
also for partials, you can omit the `_filename`;

you may been to ensure the files for directory `variables` is included

Comment: @ Denis Tsoi

I wrote to my file structure in the end of my post above.
(In meantime I changed the location of grunt, as well the paths.)

Comment: @ Ayala - I meant the project structure;

Comment: @ Denis Tsoi
I am sorry, I just wanted to write, but than I realised I couldn't edit my post.
So this is the structure:

/tarsoly/css, tarsoly/sass/tarsoly.styles.scss, tarsoly/sass/variables/_colors.scss (...)
I think this is enough.

Comment: @ Denis Tsoi Yes, I wanted edit my post how you suggested, but I can't. (Maybe because I am new, and later I will get such access.)
It doesn't matter now. So what is the mistake in my code? :)